A checkered cross - Colombian Sudoku
This is a new Colombian Sudoku that I really enjoyed creating. It’s not very complex, but it’s quite beautiful. The rules are the same as always: fill the Sudoku on the left, using the clues on the right. The number of points in a row of the table indicates how many matches it has with the corresponding row of the completed Sudoku. Bye Bye...


the answer:…………………………………………….

 

the steps:

 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 



Share the procedure.

@bobble I’ve updated my answer, please check. Actually, I have no clever understandings about the solving method, it’s just  the deduction step by step…
